# ViewController dealloc crash occurs on iOS 16

Tags: swift, crashlytics, viewcontroller, ios16, xcode14

The app was working fine with iOS 15 and Xcode 13. However, since we had to switch to Xcode 14, I updated it and it started crashing after logging in.

It doesn't happen all the time. Activated a zombie object as follows:

Navigate to Edit Schemes -> Diagnostics, and enable the check mark for Zombie objects

Crash report like this:

```
     Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001b4a1e820 objc_msgSend + 32
1   UIKitCore                       0x00000001bdbe74a4 -[UIViewController dealloc] + 772 (UIViewController.m:3102)
2   UIKitCore                       0x00000001bdbe50cc -[UINavigationController dealloc] + 308 (UINavigationController.m:786)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001bb9e2734 __RELEASE_OBJECTS_IN_THE_ARRAY__ + 116 (NSCollectionAux.h:70)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001bb981b94 -[__NSFrozenArrayM dealloc] + 124 (NSCopyOnWrite.h:229)
5   UIKitCore                       0x00000001be1539ec -[UIMoreListController .cxx_destruct] + 76 (UIMoreListController.m:58)
6   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001b4a1e0a4 object_cxxDestructFromClass(objc_object*, objc_class*) + 116 (objc-class.mm:456)
7   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001b4a22e00 objc_destructInstance + 80 (objc-runtime-new.mm:8628)
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001b4a2c4fc _objc_rootDealloc + 80 (NSObject.mm:2138)
9   UIKitCore                       0x00000001bdbe78d8 -[UIResponder dealloc] + 124 (UIResponder.m:184)
10  UIKitCore                       0x00000001bdbe75dc -[UIViewController dealloc] + 1084 (UIViewController.m:3133)
11  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001b4a1e0a4 object_cxxDestructFromClass(objc_object*, objc_class*) + 116 (objc-class.mm:456)
12  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001b4a22e00 objc_destructInstance + 80 (objc-runtime-new.mm:8628)
13  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001b4a2c4fc _objc_rootDealloc + 80 (NSObject.mm:2138)
14  UIKitCore                       0x00000001bdbe78d8 -[UIResponder dealloc] + 124 (UIResponder.m:184)
15  UIKitCore                       0x00000001bdbe75dc -[UIViewController dealloc] + 1084 (UIViewController.m:3133)
16  UIKitCore                       0x00000001bdbe50cc -[UINavigationController dealloc] + 308 (UINavigationController.m:786)
17  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001b4a1e1d4 AutoreleasePoolPage::releaseUntil(objc_object**) + 196 (NSObject.mm:938)
18  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001b4a21bdc objc_autoreleasePoolPop + 256 (NSObject.mm:2186)
19  UIKitCore                       0x00000001bdb87444 -[_UIAfterCACommitBlock run] + 92 (_UIAfterCACommitQueue.m:155)
20  UIKitCore                       0x00000001bdb87364 -[_UIAfterCACommitQueue flush] + 168 (_UIAfterCACommitQueue.m:228)
21  UIKitCore                       0x00000001bdb87278 _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks + 496 (UIApplication.m:3249)
22  UIKitCore                       0x00000001bda25ee4 _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks + 108 (UIApplication.m:3213)
23  UIKitCore                       0x00000001bdee4608 _UIApplicationFlushCATransaction + 72 (UIApplication.m:3290)
24  UIKitCore                       0x00000001be034e00 _UIUpdateSequenceRun + 84 (_UIUpdateSequence.mm:114)
25  UIKitCore                       0x00000001be698944 schedulerStepScheduledMainSection + 144 (_UIUpdateScheduler.m:1015)
26  UIKitCore                       0x00000001be697ea0 runloopSourceCallback + 92 (_UIUpdateScheduler.m:1116)
27  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001bba4c208 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 28 (CFRunLoop.c:1957)
28  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001bba58864 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 176 (CFRunLoop.c:2001)
29  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001bb9dd6c8 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 244 (CFRunLoop.c:2038)
30  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001bb9f31c4 __CFRunLoopRun + 828 (CFRunLoop.c:2953)
31  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001bb9f84dc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612 (CFRunLoop.c:3418)
32  GraphicsServices                0x00000001f6c5835c GSEventRunModal + 164 (GSEvent.c:2196)
33  UIKitCore                       0x00000001bdd8437c -[UIApplication _run] + 888 (UIApplication.m:3773)
34  UIKitCore                       0x00000001bdd83fe0 UIApplicationMain + 340 (UIApplication.m:5363)
```

I couldn't find any information on why it happened or how to detect it.

Comment: as per my understanding you are trying to dealloc `UINavigationController` when you are trying to go back to root controller

Comment: The crash report indicates that the crash occurs during the deallocation of a UIViewController. It seems that the UIViewController is already deallocated, but some code is still trying to access it, leading to the crash.

Comment: @Jatin Do you have any suggestions to solve or detect

Comment: @JobinsJohn Do you have any suggestions to solve or detect

Comment: can you share some code when you are trying to jump on next controller and deinit method of both controller so we can decide whats happening there.

Comment: @OMANSAK Please share your code so that we can have a look.

Comment: I have a login view controller where I log in to the application, then I have view controllers in UITabBarController. Their deinit methods do not work when I log out. When I log in and set rootViewController again, it starts clearing. @JobinsJohn

Comment: I have a login view controller where I log in to the application, then I have view controllers in UITabBarController. Their deinit methods do not work when I log out. When I log in and set rootViewController again, it starts clearing. @Jatin

Comment: @Jatin if getLoggedInUser() == nil {
            window?.rootViewController = WelcomeViewController(nibName: String(describing: WelcomeViewController.self), bundle: nil)
        } else {
            let viewController = ViewController(nibName: String(describing: ViewController.self), bundle: nil)
            AppDelegate().sharedInstance().window?.rootViewController = viewController
          
        }

No rows are given in crash report

Comment: @JobinsJohn if getLoggedInUser() == nil { window?.rootViewController = WelcomeViewController(nibName: String(describing: WelcomeViewController.self), bundle: nil) } else { let viewController = ViewController(nibName: String(describing: ViewController.self), bundle: nil) AppDelegate().sharedInstance().window?.rootViewController = viewController } No rows are given in crash report

Comment: @OMANSAK can you sjare piece of code show we can find out the issues.

Answer (score -1):

I just added `.animation(.default, value: repository.state)` and didn't get crashes anymore.

Comment: where did you add this?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @OMANSAK I added it in the `ContentView` where I am switching views based on user state i.e. user being signed in / out.